# On OSMC, how do I get to NOOBS?

Tags: raspbian

I have gone to OSMC -  Programs - OSMC Settings 0.0.1 - Logging -   and can't figure out what's next.  Also tried Settings-Pi, but can't figure out what's next.  Welcome any ideas!

Comment: If you mean you installed OSMC on a NOOBS card I would guess you can't -- OSMC doesn't know about NOOBS.   To switch OS's you'd have to reboot.

Answer (score 1):

If you installed OSMC using noobs then you should restart and hold down the shift key will booting up.

Answer (score 0):

As already stated in the comments, you can't.

A commonly used workaround is adding your own script that changes the boot OS like so:

```
#!/bin/bash
cd ~
mount /dev/mmcblk0p1 noobs
cd noobs
mv autoboot.txt autobootkodi.txt
mv autobootother.txt autoboot.txt
reboot
```

In the other OS you do the opposite of the above as a shutdown script.